# Dropbox api gets direct file url for streaming

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I am using dropbox api to lest files in public folder with endpoint https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder

```
https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder
```

Response is something like this:

```
{
"entries": [
    {
        ".tag": "file",
        "name": "01.mp4",
        "path_lower": "/video/01.mp4",
        "path_display": "/video/01.mp4",
        "parent_shared_folder_id": "3022865105",
        "id": "id:FDeU6KOzmRUAAAAAAAAABw",
        "client_modified": "2022-09-14T15:54:42Z",
        "server_modified": "2022-09-14T16:06:36Z",
        "rev": "5e8a55037c991b42d42d1",
        "size": 12347528,
        "sharing_info": {
            "read_only": false,
            "parent_shared_folder_id": "3022865105",
            "modified_by": "dbid:AACtZetM6hKYpGsPZvtNDZUFRldH8r35OSk"
        },
        "is_downloadable": true,
        "content_hash": "7e6d5e0d1947523808762a6fc34fec7651393ef9d4f4ea2a64fb71acaf3a1240"
    },
    {
        ".tag": "file",
        "name": "02.mp4",
        "path_lower": "/video/02.mp4",
        "path_display": "/video/02.mp4",
        "parent_shared_folder_id": "3022865105",
        "id": "id:FDeU6KOzmRUAAAAAAAAACA",
        "client_modified": "2022-09-14T15:54:42Z",
        "server_modified": "2022-09-14T16:06:36Z",
        "rev": "5e8a55037c992b42d42d1",
        "size": 18791452,
        "sharing_info": {
            "read_only": false,
            "parent_shared_folder_id": "3022865105",
            "modified_by": "dbid:AACtZetM6hKYpGsPZvtNDZUFRldH8r35OSk"
        },
        "is_downloadable": true,
        "content_hash": "93d33bf10fa4e5c340dac84ebafb54d0b2759cc6e801da8ab03ae14783365fac"
    }
],
"cursor": "AAGUGbHG7ju_3pegzOTPruYbexWxEXYyJGNt5Rt1Frj8QAj_JFDTwppfDTneAq-pMfGEbX4i-aDRndn8j-MrAiLy4mCUDc8-GU_XsUdAoShGXtzWKDsDaQwWCHFmhOo0bBuXElarr3Rdil9pTMqkMcfG2hSZPeepDL_omI0Oo0a-_suATq_zoBrH-o2zNKe9-udR2UrsgPuMl9toei-Tt19FCLHX4uzyT6xAXJjFKnWdfj7y3lgyoxrJqtQPVBc1WT0",
"has_more": false
}
```

My question is how do I get a direct url link to each file in such a way that I can use it in (let's say) an html5 video tag?

When I right click on a file inside a dropbox folder, the url is something like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/305pjdhly2w948y/01.mp4?dl=0

How do I get a direct url like this from this response?

Comment: Don't you need to share it first? https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file

Comment: But I want to get url for each file in the folder which is public. Does this mean I have to run get_shared_link_file for each file I get in response from folder?

Comment: `/get_temporary_link` should work even if it's not shared. Of course link is temporary, giving 410 error a few hours after its creation. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link

Comment: Are you looking for https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download?

Comment: @GrafiCode - I dont want temporary link, I want non expiring link if possible.  I make my folder sharable by right clicking on the folder itself and select share. But like I said in my post, I read folder so I can get all files first (this works), then I need to construct / get direct url to each file.

Comment: @Toniq if you made your folder shareable, you got a link for that folder. If you navigate to that link in private/incognito mode, you should see all your files. Hover over them to see what _their_ URL looks like. You should be able to construct the URL for each file based on that.

Comment: @robertklep - I have written example of url of a file when I right click in my post (   https://www.dropbox.com/s/305pjdhly2w948y/01.mp4?dl=0 ) . This is the same file from the folder response.  I dont see how I can make this from the response data I got.

Comment: @Toniq that's the URL for a file, I was talking about the URL for a folder. Those are distinctly different.

Comment: Sorry ,  I dont understand hat you mean. I can read folder successfully and get files inside like I have written. But how do I get / construct direct (playable) link for each file from that response? This is direct link in my folder I am reading (  https://www.dropbox.com/s/305pjdhly2w948y/01.mp4?dl=0 ) but in  folder response there is no this part anywhere:  305pjdhly2w948y

Comment: @Toniq that link is not direct to the video. Opening that link will bring you to the dropbox website, where the video (courtesy of dropbox) can be watched on the embedded player. Again, that's not a direct link. Even if you inspect the video player, you'll find the source of the video is a `blob`, not a direct link to any file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to get such links in bulk. You'll need to make a call to make a link for each file.

To get temporary direct link for a file, you would call /2/files/get_temporary_link:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a non-temporary version of that exactly, but you can create a shared link via /2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings

Or to retrieve existing shared links, use /2/sharing/list_shared_links:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links

That's the same kind of link as returned by the Dropbox web site.

Note that these shared links don't link directly to the file data though. They link to the HTML preview page for the file. You can modify them for direct or raw file access instead though as documented here:

https://help.dropbox.com/share/force-download

Comment: I tried list_shared_links but I get empty result. I have enabled sharing.read permission, its just that the result on the same folder is empty ( I used path: /video): {"links": [], "has_more": false} My folder is shared.

Comment: I get the same when I test here (empty result):  https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#sharing_list_shared_links   If I read this, it appears you cannot pass folder:  https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/list-shared-links-says-I-have-no-shared-links-but-I-do-have-them/td-p/333045    I dont understand the answer :  "So, supplying as path to a folder will not make it list the shared links for files inside that folder. If you want the shared links for a file, you need to specify the full path for the file."  I dont have full path to my files using api.

Comment: The /2/sharing/list_shared_links endpoint only returns existing shared links. The response you got with `"links": [],` indicates that the call was successful but there were no links for that path to return.

Comment: It is not possible to use /2/sharing/list_shared_links to list the shared links for the items inside a specific folder. If you specify a particular folder path, it will only return links for that folder itself, not its contents. To get shared links for everything, you would need to omit the path entirely. To get the shared links for a specific file, you need to specify the path for that file, which you can get from the `path_lower` value for the file as returned by /2/files/list_folder[/continue], e.g., as shown in your question.

Comment: Note that that only allows you to retrieve existing shared links. If the necessary shared links don't already exist, you need to create them using /2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings as described in my answer above.